# Apache Virtual Host -- How to setup a subdomain to point to a game server

Tags: apache, reverse-proxy, virtualhost, mod-proxy, proxypass

I have an apache hosted website `https://example.com` which points to some html code I have with `<VirtualHost _default_:443>`. This works fine, I use a subdomain `https://unifi.example.com`  for my Unifi Wireless Controller located at `192.168.0.xx0:8443` with `ProxyPass`. Where I am currently struggling is trying host a game server through a subdomain, `mc.example.com:19132`. The traffic needs to proxy to or be redirected to `192.168.0.xx1:19132`, where the game server is running. My current code for the virtual host mc.example.com:

```
<VirtualHost *:19132>
    ServerName mc.example.com
    ServerAdmin john-krasinski@the-office.com
    <Directory />
        #Require all denied
    </Directory>
        ProxyRequests Off
        ProxyPreserveHost On
        ProxyPass / http://192.168.0.xx1:19132/
        ProxyPassReverse / http://192.168.0.xx1:19132/
</VirtualHost>
```

I have tried *almost* everything, so any help you could offer would be greatly appreciated! Also if you believe there is a workaround to get a subdomain to point to `192.168.0.xx1:19132`, please let me know. As far as I know the only way to use subdomains on the same network is with VirtualHosts, I would very happily be proven wrong!

-PS before you ask, yes I have:

1. restarted the server
2. made sure the mod is enabled
3. made sure the ip's are correct
4. tried a local host instead of local ip because why not, right?

Thanks,

Kaden

Comment: try the examples listed here.

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/remapping.html

Comment: Do you have a `listen 192.168.1.www:19132` where www is the station where your Apache2 server runs anywhere in your config?

Comment: Dougie, I have the port listed in the ports.conf. I assume that's good enough, correct?

Comment: Rafee correct me if I'm wrong, rewriting the URL wouldn't work as external users trying to join don't have a server running at 192.168.0.xx1.